# How do I group "or" in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have legacy sql query that selects bit masks (among other data), something like:

```
1
2
1
```

How do I group this output like:

```
1 or 2 or 1
```

That should be `3`

Comment: Do you mean rows with values of `2` and `1` should get into same group? If so, you should group your resultset by function making `1` from `2` or vice versa. `GROUP BY DECODE(YOUR_COLUMN, 2, 1)` for example.

Comment: May be "group" is not exact term for what I have to do. I'd like to "or" all column data in rows. For example: 1 or 2 or 2 or 1 or 4 = 7, 1 or 4 or 1 = 5

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do bit-wise logic you have to do a "bit" of math. (Bad puns are free around here :-).

Oracle defines the BITAND function. To get a bitwise 'or' you can define your own function as:

```
FUNCTION BITOR(n1 IN NUMBER, n2 IN NUMBER) 
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN n1 - BITAND(n1, n2) + n2;
END BITOR;
```

And for completeness, BITXOR is

```
FUNCTION BITXOR(n1 IN NUMBER, n2 IN NUMBER)
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN BITOR(n1, n2) - BITAND(n1, n2);
END BITXOR;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you, Bob! What shall I do next with this function? How do I apply it to all rows data to get accumulative result?

Comment: I think you'd have to use a PL/SQL block. Open a cursor, read the rows, and accumulate the result. I can't think of a way to do this in an SQL statement, but perhaps someone wiser than me can come up with something. Best of luck.

Comment: May I achieve something if I split bit mask column into 8 (or 16) columns with 0 and 1 to represent a single bit (b1, b2, b4, b8 ... ), then apply SUMMA operator to every bit column and then combine summed single bits back: (if summa > 0 for bit column then it's 1)?

Comment: There is no SUMMA operator in Oracle. I'm guessing you meant the SUM function. I suppose you could do that but I'm not sure how this would work. I recommend that you try it out on your data and keep working on it until you get what you need.

Comment: Just adding a comment for any future readers -- there are now bitwise aggregate functions built in to Oracle 20c.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the BITAND operator for AND operation. Using this you can build logic for writing a function for BITOR. Checkout this link http://www.oracledba.co.uk/tips/bitwise_ops.htm

Comment: Thank you, Nitish. It looks like Bob proposed BITOR implementation already

Answer (score 1):

There are no aggregate bit operations in Oracle.  One method is an explicit aggregation, bit by bit:

```
select ((case when max(bitand(bits, 1)) > 0 then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when max(bitand(bits, 2)) > 0 then 2 else 0 end) +
        (case when max(bitand(bits, 4)) > 0 then 4 else 0 end) +
        (case when max(bitand(bits, 8)) > 0 then 8 else 0 end) +
        (case when max(bitand(bits, 16)) > 0 then 16 else 0 end) +
        (case when max(bitand(bits, 32)) > 0 then 32 else 0 end) +
        (case when max(bitand(bits, 64)) > 0 then 64 else 0 end) +
        (case when max(bitand(bits, 128)) > 0 then 128 else 0 end) +
       )
```

If you wanted an aggregate bitwise AND, then you would use `min()` instead of `max()`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want an aggregate bit-or function.  Oracle doesn't provide one, to my knowledge, so you have to roll your own using their ODCI (Oracle Data Cartridge Interface).  Here's a working example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE matt_bitor_aggregate_impl AS OBJECT
(
  result NUMBER,
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION matt_bitor_aggregate_impl(SELF IN OUT NOCOPY matt_bitor_aggregate_impl ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT,  
-- Called to initialize a new aggregation context
-- For analytic functions, the aggregation context of the *previous* window is passed in, so we only need to adjust as needed instead 
-- of creating the new aggregation context from scratch
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize (sctx IN OUT matt_bitor_aggregate_impl) RETURN NUMBER,
-- Called when a new data point is added to an aggregation context  
  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate (self IN OUT matt_bitor_aggregate_impl, value IN NUMBER ) RETURN NUMBER,
-- Called to return the computed aggragate from an aggregation context
  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate (self IN matt_bitor_aggregate_impl, returnValue OUT NUMBER, flags IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER,
-- Called to merge to two aggregation contexts into one (e.g., merging results of parallel slaves) 
  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge (self IN OUT matt_bitor_aggregate_impl, ctx2 IN matt_bitor_aggregate_impl) RETURN NUMBER --,
);

/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY matt_bitor_aggregate_impl IS

CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION matt_bitor_aggregate_impl(SELF IN OUT NOCOPY matt_bitor_aggregate_impl ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
BEGIN
  SELF.result := null;
  RETURN;
END;


STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize (sctx IN OUT matt_bitor_aggregate_impl) RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
  sctx := matt_bitor_aggregate_impl ();
  RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
END;


MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate (self IN OUT matt_bitor_aggregate_impl, value IN NUMBER ) RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
  IF self.result IS NULL THEN
    self.result := value;
  ELSE
    -- Logic for bitwise OR
    -- see also: http://www.oracledba.co.uk/tips/bitwise_ops.htm
    self.result := self.result - BITAND(self.result, value) + value;
  END IF;
  RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
END;

MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate (self IN matt_bitor_aggregate_impl, returnValue OUT NUMBER, flags IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
  returnValue := result;
  RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
END;

MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge (self IN OUT matt_bitor_aggregate_impl, ctx2 IN matt_bitor_aggregate_impl) RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
   -- Logic for bitwise OR
   -- see also: http://www.oracledba.co.uk/tips/bitwise_ops.htm
   self.result := self.result - BITAND(self.result, ctx2.result) + ctx2.result;
  RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
END;

END;
/

-- Now that you have a TYPE to implement the logic, here is where you define the new aggregate function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION matt_bitor_aggregate ( input NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING matt_bitor_aggregate_impl;
/

-- Here's a simple test with your test data set...
with test_data as ( 
  SELECT 1 a FROM dual UNION ALL 
  select 2 from dual union all 
  select 1 from dual  
  )
select matt_bitor_aggregate(a)
from   test_data;

-- Here is a more complex test that also highlights the fact that you can use ODCI custom aggregates with window clauses.
with test_data as ( 
  SELECT 1 a FROM dual UNION ALL 
  select 2 from dual union all 
  select 1 from dual union all 
  select 16 from dual union all 
  SELECT 18 from dual)
select a, matt_bitor_aggregate(a) over ( partition by null order by rownum rows between 1 preceding and 1 following ) from
test_data;
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Oracle 20c, you can do bitwise aggregates using the following functions:

1. BIT_AND_AGG
2. BIT_OR_AGG
3. BIT_XOR_AGG